# Proguard rules for Moshi models?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, moshi

I have an Android app (Java) that uses Moshi 1.11.0 to work with JSON responses. Take this model as an example:

```java
class Payments {
    public float amount;
    public int month, year;
}
```

When developing (and running debug variant), everything works perfectly. However, when building a release version, Proguard makes all properties become 0 when trying to read them from my model. (`payment.amount`, `payment.month`, `payment.year` are all 0).

So far, the only thing that has fixed this is by prepending the @Keep annotation before each and every one of my model declarations:

```java
@Keep
class Payments {...}
```

My question is.. Is there any other workaround that would fix this issue, without having to modify each and every one of my models?

Answer (score -2):

```
-keep class com.example.models.data.** {*;}
```